# I need to send an arbitrary text string using java.awt.Robot.send()

Tags: java, swing, awt, awtrobot

I need a way to do what is described in the first answer to this question: [Type a String using java.awt.Robot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665534/type-a-string-using-java-awt-robot)

Only I would like to avoid using the clipboard. Is there a generic way to do it without?

(Other answers to the question address printing *some* hard-coded keys, but they don't help me print "Hello, world!")

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260282/converting-a-char-into-java-keyevent-keycode).

Answer (score 1):

You can use javax.swing.KeyStroke to transform the characters in your string into keycodes. For each key code, call Robot.keyPress(...), Robot.keyRelease(...) as you are doing in your previous question

Comment: "*transform the characters in your string into keycodes*" Not a simple task at all!