# Type what I have in a String into a program

Tags: java

So I am currently trying to make a program that will type a string into a different application (Chrome). The problem that I am experiencing is that I don't really know how to make it type out strings. I think it'd be something like this

```
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ + randomString); then robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ + randomString);
```

but that didn't work. I am very new to Java and haven't used stackoverflow in a good while so I'm sorry if a part was confusing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type a String using java.awt.Robot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665534/type-a-string-using-java-awt-robot)

Comment: There should be some delay between key press and release

Comment: Some of the examples in the link I provided include delay between key press/release.