# How to Trigger Native Paste Event on Windows with Java

Tags: java, windows, paste, awtrobot

I was try to make automation software that can paste some copied data from clipboard, but get some weird behavior. I use `java.awt.Robot` to achieve this. This is the code :

```
try{
    java.awt.Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.setAutoDelay(250);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
}catch(AWTException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

How to trigger native paste event properly on Windows with Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665534/type-a-string-using-java-awt-robot

Comment: I think it's not duplicate, I get weird paste behavior if I just use `java.awt.Robot`

Comment: What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: When I use that code, I get multiple times paste event. I can make sure this method only call once, because I was logging it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem and the paste event work as expected. Because my project using JavaFX, there is 2 solution here using `java.awt.Robot`

```
try{
    java.awt.Robot r = new Robot();
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
}catch(AWTException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or `javafx.scene.robot.Robot`

```
javafx.scene.robot.Robot r = new javafx.scene.robot.Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyCode.CONTROL);
r.keyPress(KeyCode.V);
r.keyRelease(KeyCode.CONTROL);
r.keyRelease(KeyCode.V);
```

I choose using `javafx.scene.robot.Robot`, because in some situation `java.awt.Robot` not work properly